# No module named _QuantLib, Quantlib-Python installation

Tags: python, installation, quantlib

I am trying to install Quantlib-Python on my Mac ([official instructions](http://quantlib.org/install/macosx-python.shtml)), but when I run `make -C Python check`, I receive an error `ImportError: No module named _QuantLib`. When I revisit the installation steps it seems like everything is working:

```
Removing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/QuantLib_Python-1.9-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/QuantLib_Python-1.9-py2.7.egg-info
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: That means your C++ installation is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Python might be failing to find your dynamic C++ QuantLib library.  It should probably be called `libQuantLib.dylib` and should be where the dynamic loader can find it; that means that it should be in some standard system location like `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`, or that you should set the environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that it includes its location.

If you only want to use the QuantLib Python module, an easier alternative might be to sidestep dynamic loading.  If you clean up your installation (that is, if you remove any `libQuantLib.*` that you might have installed) and you rebuild the C++ QuantLib by first configuring it as

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static
```

(plus any other flags you might need), when you run `make` you'll get a static library.  When you rebuild the Python wrappers, the Python module will then embed the QuantLib code itself instead of relying on the presence of the dynamic library.

Comment: Hi Luigi - I got the same error after `python setup.py install`. I tried `--disable-shared --enable-static` but `configure` complained that these flags were not recognised.. I'm running MacOS Sierra / GUN g++ 6.3 / Python 3.6. Anything you'd suggest? Thanks.

Comment: The call to configure was for building the C++ library, not the Python module.

Comment: Yes I know, I thought linking statically would help, so tried to recompile Quantlib-SWIG v1.9, that's when the error happened. Although I do see the libQuantLib.* in my /usr/local/lib folder...

Comment: I mean you should run `configure --disable-shared` when compiling QuantLib, not QuantLib-SWIG.

Comment: ah I see. I installed it with `brew install quantlib`... Thanks for the tip. I'll try the manual install sometime. those libQuant* files are actually in my /usr/local/lib folder, but even if it set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib, I still get the same error. If you have any suggestions on why that is, I'd love to know.